# Why $registrationDetails shows an empty collection instead of a collection with 2 items?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the participants associated with the registration with id "2". But with code below:

```
dd($registrationID); // shows "2".

$registrationDetails = Registration::with([
    'participants' => function ($query) use ($registrationID) {
        $query->select('id', 'ticket_type_id')->where('registration_id', $registrationID);
    }
])->find($registrationID);

dd($registrationDetails);
```

it appears an empty collection:

```
Registration {#286 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#106 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
...
}
```

But in the participants table there are 2 records where registration_id = 2.

Do you know where is the issue? Why returns an empty collection and not a collection with 2 items?

With select() already works:

```
 $registrationDetails = Registration::with([
        'participants' => function ($query) use ($registrationID) {
            $query->select()->where('registration_id', $registrationID);
        }
    ])->find($registrationID);
```

With only select() it shows the item associated with the registration:

```
Registration {#264 ▼
...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#266 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your relationship on the `Registration` model is defined like this:

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
}
```

then you don't have to use this additional query. A simple `Registration::with('participants')->find($id)` will do it. Only participants with the correct `registration_id` will be fetched due to the relationship definition.

But if you want to stay with your complicated code, the reason might be that you did not select `registration_id` as well. Without it, the Eloquent query engine cannot match the source for the participants, which is your registration. So simply use the following for your inner query:

```
$query->select('id', 'ticket_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $registrationID);
```